# Android Simple Drawing App Tutorial will not run

Tags: java, android, drawing

I'm using the code found here:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Basic-Painting-with-Views

I've copied and pasted everything in the activity xml file and the java file. When I try to run it, the app immediately crashes.

in the activity_simple_drawing_view.xml
line 6 :tools:context=".MainActivity" >
.MainActivity is red which makes me think there was a main activity that the author forgot to include in the tutorial.

android monitor:

```
06-24 14:41:29.140 1981-1981/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

                                      [ 06-24 14:41:29.140   135:  375 I/         ]
                                      HWComposer -> eventControl
06-24 14:41:29.451 1981-1981/com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp
06-24 14:41:29.457 1981-1981/com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-24 14:41:29.462 1981-1981/com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp D/ActivityThread: BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{191fcf34 com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp}}
06-24 14:41:29.465 1981-1981/com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-24 14:41:29.466 1981-1981/com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp, PID: 1981
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp/com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView has no zero argument constructor
                                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
                                                                                      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
06-24 14:41:46.418 1981-1981/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1981 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Read the stacktrace: `com.codepath.example.simpledrawapp.SimpleDrawingView has no zero argument constructor`

Comment: I wouldn't say the author forgot anything. They're just assuming that you know the basics of setting up a simple `Activity` on your own. You need a `MainActivity` that the layout shown there will be loaded into. You shouldn't be trying to "launch" `SimpleDrawingView` on its own.

Comment: @Jens Tried     public SimpleDrawingView(){} got : "There is no default constructor available in 'android.view.View'"

Comment: @Mike M. I added a main activity and connected it (correctly, I hope) but I'm left with the error message: SimpleDrawingView has no default constructors.  I tried to add an empty constructor but as you can see from the comment above, that didn't work either.

Comment: `SimpleDrawingView` should not be listed in your manifest anywhere. The `<activity>` element should be `MainActivity`. Then, in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method, you'd call `setContentView()` with the `R.layout` for the XML layout shown in the linked example. Don't try to add a zero argument constructor to `SimpleDrawingView`.

Comment: @Mike M. Thank you :)